# unable to transform the categorical variable, showing categories=auto error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, data-science, spyder

python version 3.7, spyder 3.3.6. always showing an error I have tried with different versions python also:

```
import pandas as pa
import numpy as np

X=0
y=0
dataset = 0
#import the data set and separete the 
dataset = pa.read_csv("50_Startups.csv")
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:,4].values

#categorical variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
ct = ColumnTransformer(
        [('one_hot_encoder',OneHotEncoder(),[0])],
        remainder = 'passthrough'
        )
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float64)
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

The error is:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_encoders.py:415: FutureWarning: The handling of integer data will change in version 0.22. Currently, the categories are determined based on the range [0, max(values)], while in the future they will be determined based on the unique values.
If you want the future behaviour and silence this warning, you can specify "categories='auto'".
In case you used a LabelEncoder before this OneHotEncoder to convert the categories to integers, then you can now use the OneHotEncoder directly.
      warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-5-139c661c06f7>", line 25, in <module>
        X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X), dtype=np.float64)

 File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 490, in fit_transform
        return self._hstack(list(Xs))

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py", line 541, in _hstack
        raise ValueError("For a sparse output, all columns should"

 ValueError: For a sparse output, all columns should be a numeric or convertible to a numeric.
```

Answer (score 1):

Matrix of features as X and dep variable as Y (convert dataframe to numpy array)

```
`X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values`       
`Y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values`
```

Encoding Categorical variable

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
en = LabelEncoder()
X[:,3] = en.fit_transform(X[:,3])
oh = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[3])
X = oh.fit_transform(X)  

#converting from matrix to array
X = X.toarray()
#Dummy variable trap ---- Removing one dummy variable 
X = X[:,1:]
```

Here you selecting all the columns which have numeric data.You only fit the encoder for categorical column and then transform it. And remove the dummy variable.

Comment: The 'categorical_features' keyword is deprecated. and we have a warning using the above. as per my understanding, we must use the ColumnTransformer

Comment: onehotencoder is supposed to convert to numeric beforehand anyway no?